# How can I use round brackets without making a group?

Tags: regex

I want to use round brackets for using logical operators, but without making a group for matching.

I’ll explain with an example:

```
/(synn|pack)\sRim.*?vert(\s\d*cm|\d*cm)/
```

The first group is `(synn|pack)`. How can I make it `OR` without making it a group, so than in this regex I'll have only one group `(\s\d*cm|\d*cm)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a *non-capturing group*. If the first characters after the opening parens of a group are `?:`, then the group isn’t captured. So in this example, you’d replace the `(synn|pack)` group with `(?:synn|pack)`.

Here’s an illustration with Python (the `.groups` attribute counts how many groups a regex has):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(r'(synn|pack)\sRim.*?vert(\s\d*cm|\d*cm)').groups
2
>>> re.compile(r'(?:synn|pack)\sRim.*?vert(\s\d*cm|\d*cm)').groups
1
```

See [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/1558022) for more details.

Comment: Could you please tell me how can i make every group after ``OR`` be the first group. ``(?:-(\d*) | \s(\d*) | (\d*))cm`` - Here i have 3 groups

Comment: @Src: What is the regex flavor? What you ask for is not possible in some languages. (BTW, the example above can be written as `[-\s]?(\d*)`)